# How to catching file open events

Tags: entity-framework

Is there a class in the .NET framework that I can used to catch files being opened? FileSystemWatcher only fires when a file is altered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) can monitor changes to the [`LastAccess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.notifyfilters.aspx#memberList) (= "The date the file or folder was last opened") attribute - this should do what you want.